# Create several columns with one loop in a "select" statement in PySpark

Tags: python, loops, select, pyspark

I would like to know if it's possible to loop several columns at the same time with a select statement in PySpark.

Below, there is the type of code (this is an example) i would like to run but with a select statement

(Imagine Test is a dataframe with few columns but they are useless here)

```
Test1=Test.withColumn("a1", lit(1))
Test1=Test1.withColumn("b1", lit(5))
for i in range(2,100):
    Test1=Test1.withColumn("a"+str(i), col("a"+str(i-1))*col("b"+str(i-1)))
    Test1=Test1.withColumn("b"+str(i), col("a"+str(i))+1)
```

As you can see, I want to create 100 colums "a" and 100 columns "b". But, "a" needs the value of the previous iteration of the columns "a" and "b". AND at the same time "b" needs the value of the column "a" of the same iteration.

I wanted to use two functions to do something like this :

```
Test1.select("*", *( ( make_cola(i) , make_colb(i) for i in range(2, 100))
```

make_cola(i) and make_colb(i) are two functions which contains the expression of a and b of the code above (the part of code with the withColumn).

```
def make_cola(i):
    return (col("a"+str(i-1))*col("b"+str(i-1))).alias("a{0}".format(i))
```

The code with the "select" doesn't work (it's logical) because it's not the good syntax.
So, can you help me to do the part of the code with the .withColumn but with the .select ?

Thank you,

Comment: have you tried list comprehension within the select statement?

Comment: I don't know how i can use a list comprehension here to solve my issue